# How to change the counterion of a nucleotide salt?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, ionic-compounds, chromatography

I need to take the sodium nucleotide salts I have available in my lab and modify them to instead contain some more exotic counterions. Can I do this by binding my nucleotides to a strong anion exchange resin, washing, and eluting with a salt of my preferred counter ion? Seems like it should work, but Im a biologist, not a chemist. Any other suggestions would also be appreciated! Thanks very much!

Comment: Ion-exchange chromatography is typically used to achieve that. This is how ionic liquids get their different "exotic" anions.